# Get HTTPWebResponse details after sending request

Tags: .net, jmeter, httprequest, httpresponse, system.diagnostics

Using .Net Framework's System.Diagnostics library, i want to simulate something similar to what i'm getting using JMeter. Basically i want to be able to send an HTTPWebRequest and from the response, i want to get the following details as accurately as i can:

- The Response Time (in seconds)
- The Response Size (in KBs)
- The Response Rate (in KB/s) without embedded resources

Currently i have the following code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.Method = HTTPRequestType.GET.ToString();
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36";

        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
        watch.Stop();

        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webResponse;
        Stream streamResponse = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
```

With this code i can get the response time from the watch's ElapsedTime property. How do i go about getting the rest of the data i want, and am i missing any important properties i need to set in my request to make the simulation as accurate as possible (things like cookies, caching, user-agent...etc)?

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? It's not a little job

Comment: Im currently doing it through JMeter and i need to decouple from it.

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve? Develop JmeterNext(r)???

Comment: Seriously StackOverflow... that's all i'm getting? An interrogation? This is starting to sound like a conversation with my wife :/